# UIWebView loadHTMLString:baseURL: offline cache manifest issue

Tags: ios, caching, uiwebview, manifest, offline

I have an issue with UIWebView and offline cache. I don't know if it's a Webkit bug or not. Let me explain what the issue is.

For my example I'm using the Apple's Checkers demo available here: https://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/Checkers/ (I'm sure that the manifest works).

So I'm creating a UWebView and loading the request like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/Checkers/"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

To verify if the device has cached files included in the .manifest file I'm going to check it in the application folder.

APP_FOLDER/Library/Caches/xxxx.manifest/ApplicationCache.db

in the ApplicationCache.db:

```
SELECT * FROM CacheResources;
```

gives me all cached resources included in the manifest (nice it works !!).

Now I quit the app, shut down the network connection and launch the app again. The game loads fine as expected with no network connection.

Now, here my issue.

Instead of using NSURLRequest to load my webView, I want to use an HTML string (because my third API send me html text through json)

UIWebView will be loaded like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/Checkers/"];

NSString *html = @"<html manifest=\"OfflineCheckers.manifest\"><head><title>Checkers</title><script>window.applicationCache.onupdateready = function() { console.log(\"Swapping in new applicationCache\"); applicationCache.swapCache(); }</script><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=640,user-scalable=no\" /><meta name=\"apple-mobile-web-app-capable\" content=\"yes\" /><meta name=\"apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style\" content=\"black\" /><link rel=\"icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\" /><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" href=\"resources/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-startup-image\" href=\"resources/startup.png\"/><link href=\"resources/Checkers.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" /><link href=\"resources/Achievements.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" /><link href=\"resources/HighScores.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" /><link href=\"resources/EndGame.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" /><link href=\"resources/GameManager.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" /><link href=\"resources/Utilities.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" /></head><body onload=\"initializeScreen();\"><script src=\"resources/Achievements.js\"></script><script src=\"resources/AIOpponent.js\"></script><script src=\"resources/Checkers.js\"></script><script src=\"resources/EndGame.js\"></script><script src=\"resources/GameManager.js\"></script><script src=\"resources/HighScores.js\"></script><script src=\"resources/Utilities.js\"></script><div id=\"GameParent\"></div><script>document.body.board = new CheckerBoard(document.getElementById(\"GameParent\"));</script></body></html>";
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:url];
```

I'm first deleting the app to delete all previous cached resources. Then set the network connection ON and launch the app. The same thing happens, webview is loaded, resources are cached...

Now if I'm shutting down the network connection, the webView will no longer load. It's like calling loadHTMLString:baseURL: do not use the application cache.

I know there is a solution consisting in downloading all offline resources in the app document folder and set the baseURL to that folder but HTML 5 offline cache manifest is here to take care of it so I want to use it. Is there any way to fix my issue ? Any help is welcome.

Thanks guys.